# Cómo mostrar datos de una consulta PHP-MS Access

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

Estoy haciendo un programa dónde recojo datos de MS Access y los muestro en pantalla con PHP. Dejo el código:

```
$query="SELECT `DNI` FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='32453154'";
    $test=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $query);
    $dnisMS=odbc_fetch_array($test);
    var_dump($dnisMS);

    for($i=0; $i<(count($dnisMS)-1); $i++){
          
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$dnisMS[$i]."</td>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
```

El caso es que el var_dump si me muestra la variable correspondiente, pero luego no me entra en el for y no me lo muestra en pantalla. No tengo ni idea de por qué no entra en el for. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Seguramente te falta indicar la columna que quieres mostrar `$dnisMS[$i]['DNI']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas marear tanto los datos (usando dos bucles, el `while` y luego un `for`). Puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
$query="SELECT `DNI` FROM pedidos WHERE IdPedido='32453154'";
$test=odbc_exec($conMSAccess, $query);
while ( $dnisMS=odbc_fetch_array($test) ){
    echo "<tr><td>$dnisMS[DNI]</td><tr>";
}
```

Se supone que completas bien tu `<table>`, de lo contrario puede que no veas la tabla HTML ni los `<tr>`.

#### Variaciones en el código

- He usado un solo `echo` para todo el `<tr>`
- `odbc_fetch_array()` devuelve un array asociativo y he usado la notación `$objeto['columna']` para obtener el `<td>`, aunque sin comillas, debido a que se usa dentro de una cadena con comillas dobles.

Así debería funcionar. Si no entiendes algo pregunta en comentarios.

Comment: Pues no funciona y no comprendo por qué. Salta este error: "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_fetch_assoc() ". ¿Puede ser porque sea un método muy antiguo y estoy usando PHP 7.2 para ejecutarlo? Gracias, saludos.

Comment: @Sergio, perdona, prueba así: `while ( $dnisMS=odbc_fetch_array($test) ){`, pues `odbc_fetch_assoc()` no existe.

Comment: Y si quiero hacer una consulta que en la BBDD el campo tiene un espacio entre medias¿? Porque pongo este código...

``` $query="SELECT `nombre cliente` FROM pedidos WHERE poblacion='Madrid'";

pero claro, nombre cliente me da error, pero sin embargo en la BBDD tiene espacio. ¿Cómo se pondría en PHP a la hora de ejecutar la consulta?

Comment: @Sergio, lee el último punto al final de la respuesta. Para leer los datos debes usar el nombre de la/s columna/s. Si en la nueva consulta hay una columna llamada `nombre cliente`, debes ponerlo así: `echo "<tr><td>$dnisMS[nombre cliente]</td><tr>";` OJO: **evita usar espacios en nombres de columna, te podría fastidiar el código y te obliga a usar siempre backticks en esas columnas**. Si no funciona, cambia el nombre de la columna a `nombre_cliente` por ejemplo o usa un alias en la consulta SQL.

Comment: Gracias. El tema que es una BBDD que no es mía y no puedo cambiar el nombre de la columna en la BBDD ni ponerle un alias. ¿Puedo hacer algo desde el código de PHP?

Comment: Sí, con el alias me refiero al código PHP @Sergio. Algo así: `$query="SELECT [nombre cliente] AS nombre FROM pedidos WHERE poblacion='Madrid'"`  y luego puedes hacer algo así: `echo "<tr><td>$dnisMS[nombre]</td><tr>";`